# How to uninstall fvm (Flutter Version Manager)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to uninstall FVM and install native Flutter

I already looked in the FVM documentation but I didn't find anything, and I need to uninstall FVM and install native Flutter

Answer (score 1):

Run command **fvm list** this will output the directory used for Flutter cache. Delete that directory. If you installed using pub run **dart pub global deactivate fvm**, if you used a standalone installation please follow its instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into your C directory, then users, and there you will see a folder

```
fvm
```

you can delete it. In my case, the path is

```
C:\Users\YCB\fvm
```

And if you have installed fvm with choco, you will have to remove it from choco directory. For me, the path is

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib
```

Here you will see fvm, just delete it.